# NuGet Server With Caching

Tags: nuget, nuget-server, nugetgallery, proget, myget

I have a build server that pulls nuget packages on every build, and currently have a NugetGallery deployed internally for custom packages. Right now that eats bandwidth like no tomorrow (not a huge deal, but I want to be kind and make things faster for us).

So I want to auto-mirror repos and cache them.

So far I have a few options: MyGet, which is a cloud-only offering (so no), and Proget (which I'm leaning towards). Are there any other options for auto-mirroring I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inedo's [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget) is by far the most popular choice for on-prem NuGet servers, but both [JFrog](http://www.jfrog.com/) and [Sonatype](http://sonatype.com/) have options as well.

Answer (score 5):

[Klondike](https://github.com/themotleyfool/Klondike) is an open-source NuGet package manager that you can deploy privately to your own servers.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention whether you have multiple locations to support in your setup. If you do, I'd like to point you to this new feature developed by Inedo (ProGet) and MyGet in partnership:

http://blog.myget.org/post/2015/01/28/Introducing-MyGet-Feed-Sync.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[BaGet](https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet) is the best tool if you looking for something similar to [vardaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio) or [Devpi](https://github.com/devpi/devpi). It is opensource and capable of caching packages by enabling [read-through caching](https://loic-sharma.github.io/BaGet/configuration/#enable-read-through-caching)